# Does QNX support copy-on-write for child process?

Tags: qnx, mmu, copy-on-write

As we know on Linux, after the parent process creates a child process by using `fork`, the child process will have the same memory map as the parent process for the data segment.
When the child process modifies some variables, the Linux kernel will catch this access, and create a page, copy it, and remap this page for the child process, then the new value actually goes into the new page, this is the copy-on-write what I am talking about.
As we know, QNX is a real-time OS, so my question is whether QNX has this mechanism?